# Why use != null in if statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement, null, coding-style

I come from a C/C++ background and recently started a new job doing C# work.  I find in a lot of code and examples online people use this convention in if statements

```
if(obj != null)
```

I remember being told to avoid using negative logic when possible.  So why isn't something like

```
if(obj)
```

used instead?  Is there a code standard that states to use the former style of coding?  I would think that these two statements evaluate the same, but perhaps they evaluate differently?

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: You mean, why does your other option not compile?  (it's not a "convention")

Comment: An if statement's expression needs to evaluate to a boolean.

Comment: @Josh so why not take like 10 seconds to verify if what you think is actually true?

Comment: @Josh, no, they do not both compile.

Comment: @Josh perhaps you need to read this [C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_decision_making.htm) also if the variable in question that you are trying to compare is of type `Boolean` then you could use the `if(variable){}` construct

Comment: Using "positive" logic would require an else because you usually only want to do something if obj is *not* null.  VB has an easy way to do a positive null test (`If obj Is Nothing Then...`) but it is still more common to do `If obj IsNot Nothing...` to take into account the case you are specifically looking for. (bool aspects aside)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if` expressions have to be *boolean*. Say I have a string:

```
string test = null;
```

`if (test)` won't compile because `test` *is not a bool*. It just returns the string reference. So, to check for null, you actually *have to check for null*:

`if (test != null)` is an expression that *does* return a bool, and so compiles, and is a standard way of checking for null.

Answer (score 6):

The simple fact is, that C# has *and uses* a true boolean type. An `if` expects a boolean. So `if(obj)` is a syntax error if `obj` is anything but a boolean.

Comment: `obj` doesn't need to be a boolean. if you have an implicit conversion defined from your type to bool then `if(obj)` will be valid.